# Single regular Expression to have CSV as well as xlsx file format

Tags: java, regex, csv

I have a regular expression `"^[\\p{Alnum}\\_]+\\.csv$"` which actually checks for the file name pattern. If pattern doesn't match i.e. abc.csv then it throws validation error.
Since we also need to support the xlsx format, file name can also be abc.xlsx.
Is there any way to modify the same regular expression to have file format for csv and xlsx?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just put both `csv` and `xlsx` inside a group delimited by regex alternation operator.

```
"^[\\p{Alnum}_]+\\.(?:xlsx|csv)$"
```

Comment: @AnshulRai this is java. In java `\\p{Alnum}` will match any alphanumeric character.

Comment: Learn from mistakes, like I did :-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try this and let you know